# android scrollbar thumb length

Tags: android

I am using a drawable for scrollbar track and thumb, in the case of thumb, I need to see the thumb in the original dimensions of the image, currently the thumb is stretched.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 (for horizontal plus 3 for vertical) protected methods in `View` that are used to calculate how to draw the scrollbar and thumb, and you can override them. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#computeHorizontalScrollExtent%28%29) and the following methods.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own style for scrollbar. Add below code in styles.

```
<style name="style_name">  
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scroller_thumb</item>
</style>
```

Then apply your style to the scrollbar.

```
style="@style/style_name"
```

You can set scrollview size using xml

```
android:scrollbarSize="0dip"
```

Or you have to set scrollview programatically.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams scrollParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height,2.0f);
scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollParams);
```